# No Emultators attached for Visual Studio Xamarin Android project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I created a Xamarin.Forms project in Visual Studio 2015. When I try to debug the deployment fails and the Output Window says "Please select a valid device before running the application." But the dropdown list for the emulators is empty. I started the AvD Manager and added an emulator but the list in Visual Studio is still empty.

Any tips?

[image: Emulator list in VS 2015]

[image: AvD Administrator]

**Update**

This solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22701822/1273885) worked for me. Thanks a lot to Ads!

Answer (score 0):

That way will get you the Android Emulators with the original Android Emulator. However if you want to use something faster I would recommend the Visual Studio Android Emulator.

Open up Visual Studio Android Emulator, normally under your start menu but here if you need it.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\emulatormgr.exe" /sku:android

Then these emulators will appear in Visual Studio and use the Visual Studio Android Emulator. If you do decide to use this emulator, also please make sure that you don't have Android Player or Genymotion installed as they will conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same issue. I managed to get it working by going to Xamarin options and updated.

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]